# Does a ActionScript/Flash equvialant to Java GetDocumentBase() exist?

Tags: java, flash, actionscript

Is there a Actionscript/Flash equivalent to Java's GetDocumentBase() Method?
I'm trying to figure out if I can create events depending on what url the flash object was loaded from.

If the object is loaded at www.Happywifi.com show a happy face animation. If it is loaded at 
www.Happywifi.com/question/ Show a question mark face.

I'm interested in flash, it seems like more detailed animations are possible with flash that what we are using in Java.

For the love of God please don't respond with "Why are you doing it that way!". The platform we are working with has a few constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the LoaderInfo class [(check out the docs)](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html)

You could use either the url property or the loaderURL property. Like this:

```
trace(root.loaderInfo.loaderURL)
```

Comment: Thanks Zevan! That's what I was looking for. I'm not familiar with Flash at all. Your answer saved me a lot of pain.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [`LoaderInfo`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html) class which has the [`loaderURL`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#loaderURL) property.

Something like:

```
stage.loaderInfo.loaderURL
```

Which will give you a string of the URL from where the file was loaded. Then you can do your additional processing.

Note that this is not the URL from which the page that was contains this object, but rather the actual URL of where the .swf file resides.

Using [flash vars](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html) might be another solution to your problem if you can embed different objects on the page depending on what you want.